# Shut down the computer quickly?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, shutdown, windows-process

I'm using an application which shuts down my computer after a fixed amount of time, using Process.Start("shutdown", "-s"). It takes about half a minute to shut down when this event is fired, as opposed to when I press "Shut down" from the Start Menu, and it does so very quickly. Is there any way to shutdown the computer programmatically, without the large delay, so that when I press a button the computer starts shutting down quickly? I'm aware that I can use the Shut Down button, but I'd like to have the option on the application.

Comment: Is the 1 a delay parameter? Could I do shutdown -s -t 20 if I wanted to shutdown in 20 seconds?

Comment: -t 1 means wait for one second before shutting down (default is 30 seconds)

Comment: And is "-s -t 1" part of the same parameter?

Comment: -s means shutdown -t is time delay (you can use 0 for immediate), -f will force close programs.  type shutdown on command prompt with no parameters and it will explain all parameters to you.

Comment: If someone could collate this into an answer I can accept it :). Thanks both!